# Function modifies inputs when not intended

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists:

```
years = [2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]    
GamsVars = ['scen_name','timefile']
settings = ['ScenarioA','s']
```

I have a function meant to return a list exactly like settings but with years appended to the relevant entries:

```
def AppendYearToSettings(year,GamsVarsIn,SettingsIn):
    SettingsOut = SettingsIn
    SettingsOut[GamsVarsIn.index('scen_name')] = SettingsIn[GamsVarsIn.index('scen_name')] + "\\" + str(year)
    SettingsOut[GamsVarsIn.index('timefile')] = SettingsIn[GamsVarsIn.index('timefile')] + str(year)
    return(SettingsOut)
```

When I test out the function in a loop:

```
for y in years:
    ysettings = AppendYearToSettings(y,GamsVars,settings)
    print(ysettings)
```

My `ysettings` is appending years cumulatively:

```
['ScenarioA\\2013', 's2013']
['ScenarioA\\2013\\2014', 's20132014']
['ScenarioA\\2013\\2014\\2015', 's201320142015']
['ScenarioA\\2013\\2014\\2015\\2016', 's2013201420152016']
['ScenarioA\\2013\\2014\\2015\\2016\\2017', 's20132014201520162017']
['ScenarioA\\2013\\2014\\2015\\2016\\2017\\2018', 's201320142015201620172018']
```

I've tried explicitly preventing settings (the original settings) from being modified, but it seems that my function is somehow modifying settings.

What is the reason that is causing this problem?

Comment: You are creating a reference in SettingsOut=SettingsIn. When you change SettingsOut, you change SettingsIn. Make a copy instead, e.g. b=a[:].

Comment: Maybe what you need is `copy.deepcopy()`, from `copy` module

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise that the "=" wasn't a one-way right to left assignment operator. This answers the question!

Comment: It *is* a one-way, right-to-left assignment operator. But you have to understand what "assignment" means in Python. I highly recommend reading [this explanation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) written by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the reason that is causing this problem?

When you are doing `SettingsOut = SettingsIn`, you are only creating another reference to the object referenced by `SettingsIn`. If you want to make a copy of the list, you can do this:

```
SettingsOut = SettingsIn[:]
```

Or, you can use [copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html) (you need to import `copy` to use this). You need this only when the elements of the list are themselves references, and you want to create new copies of the objects as well. Take a look at the comment by John Y below.

```
SettingsOut = copy.deepcopy(SettingsIn)
```

Check this out:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l2 is l1
True
>>> id(l1)
24640248
>>> id(l2)
24640248

>>> l2 = l1[:]
>>> l2 is l1
False
>>> id(l2)
24880432
>>> id(l1)
24640248
>>>
```

---

So your function could be like this:

```
def AppendYearToSettings(year,GamsVarsIn,SettingsIn):
    SettingsOut = SettingsIn[:]
    SettingsOut[GamsVarsIn.index('scen_name')] = SettingsIn[GamsVarsIn.index('scen_name')] + "\\" + str(year)
    SettingsOut[GamsVarsIn.index('timefile')] = SettingsIn[GamsVarsIn.index('timefile')] + str(year)
    return SettingsOut

for y in years:
    ysettings = AppendYearToSettings(y, GamsVars, settings)
    print(ysettings)
```

Output:

```
['ScenarioA\\2013', 's2013']
['ScenarioA\\2014', 's2014']
['ScenarioA\\2015', 's2015']
['ScenarioA\\2016', 's2016']
['ScenarioA\\2017', 's2017']
['ScenarioA\\2018', 's2018']
```

---

A little astray this, but you should take a look at the [PEP style guide for function naming](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) ;-) It says:

> Function Names
>
> Function names should be lowercase, with words
> separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
> prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
> compatibility.

Comment: This solves my problem. I treated "=" like a right-to-left assignment operator instead of a reference, and that was my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @tony You should accept the answer then, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: This is not correct use of the terms "shallow" and "deep" copying, at least for Python. When two names refer to the *same object* (such as `SettingsOut = SettingsIn`), then it's not any kind of copy. The slice-copy idiom (`SettingsOut = SettingsIn[:]`) makes a *shallow* copy. If you are working with lists, this is the same as doing `SettingsOut = list(SettingsIn)`. Why it's a copy is that you wind up with two *separate* lists. Why it's *shallow* is that if any of the *elements* are themselves references, then only the references are copied, not the referred-to objects.

Comment: Deep copying, on the other hand, tries its best to make duplicates of all the objects, "all the way down". Why I say *tries* is because due to recursive references, or to certain tricky types of objects, it is not always possible to make a full duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohnY, I will edit. It's good to have learned the use of these terms in python context. :-)